# Counterweights in the overhang problem

Tags: mathematics

In their amazing paper [Overhang](https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/people/academic/Mike.Paterson/papers/overhang.pdf) (*Amer. Math. Monthly* **116** (2009), 19–44), Mike Paterson and Uri Zwick revisited the old chestnut of how much of an overhang one can achieve by stacking bricks at the edge of a table. Crucial to their new results was the idea that a brick can have more than one other brick placed directly on top of it, thus serving as a counterweight.

I am curious about earlier examples of people who considered the possibility of stacking more than one brick on top of a given brick.  Paterson and Zwick mention a few such precursors on the second page of their paper, but I have found one other instance not mentioned by them.  In the book [*Ingenious Mathematical Problems and Methods*](http://alum.mit.edu/www/tchow/overhang.pdf) by L. A. Graham, there are several pictures of arrangements that stack more than one brick on another brick.  These were sent in by Graham's readers; curiously, Graham did not bother to analyze them, but breezily dismissed them all as "marvels of graceful instability."

Are there other precursors of Paterson and Zwick's work?

Comment: That is freakin' awesome!  I  especially like their point that nobody ever thought to codify the "one brick per layer" rule; it was just taken for granted.